# Model validation for double input field in server and client side

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Lets say i have a property with double type

```
[Display(Name = "Retail")]
public double Price { get; set; }
```

in view

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control",@type="number",@min=0 } })
```

as for now ,if the user did not enter anything or delete the value in this textbox.null will be pass to the controller on submit.

anyway to auto assign value of 0 to it without writing manual javascript to each and every field for the double/int/long number field by default?

**My Model**

```
public partial class Product
{
}
public class ProductsAttribute
{
    [Display(Name = "Retail")]
    [Range(0, double.MaxValue)]
    public double Price{ get; set; }     
}
```

**Database first generated class**`

```
public partial class Product
{           
   public Product()
   {              
      this.Machines = new HashSet<Machine>();
   }

   public double Price { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<Machine> WMFMachines { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can't you set the default value in the constructor of model?

Comment: Writing `=0` in your controller's param could do the trick, right ?

Comment: One trick you can make property of column null able. it will save null value if the user not enter any value

Comment: if i am using this in 3 pages. i need that in controller 3 times?And if my entity have more than 3. means i need to assign it 9 times in 3 pages.

In constructor:user press backspace and the value will be gone. when submit. it will still be null.

Comment: you can use costructor method of class to make price zero after the model called

Comment: @AsifRaza that will cause error when you want to display the data or assign the value to another entity. example `TotalPrice=Price+Tax` this will throw error when price is null

Comment: @MVCnewbie you can use costructor method of class to make price zero after the model called

Comment: The property is not `nullable` so it will be initialized to zero in the POST method. Ad if you have implemented client side validation, you wont even be able to submit unless the input has a valid number.

Comment: @MVCnewbie did you check the fiddle? It works with server and client side validation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `required` attribute and model validation for server side validaition to control if user put null value in your input. You can also use client-side validation and check the input element before form submission.

I have added NetFiddle works [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fuZfRX) with server and client side validation

Client-side reference: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/718004/ASP-NET-MVC-Client-Side-Validation

**//model**

```
public class YourModel
{

   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Price is required")]
   [Display(Name = "Retail")]
   [Range(0, double.MaxValue)]
   public double Price { get; set; }

}
```

**//controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new YourModel());
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index( YourModel model)
{               
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //model is valid, add your code here 
    }
    else
    {
        //returns with model validation error
        return View();
    }

}
```

**// html**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
      .......
}
@section Scripts 
{
    Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**// web.config**

```
<configuration>
 <appSettings>  
   <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
   <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
 </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: what if the user itchy hand press the back spacing and remove the value and submit?

Comment: You can add required data.annatotaions to field to  validate your field with model.state.IsValid

Comment: The property is `double`. Its already initialized to zero. The constructor is pointless!

Comment: @user true also. i keep having this mindset that zero is not required. since zero is a value also i should set required as well

Answer (score 0):

Set it in the constructor

```
public class ViewModel
{
   public ViewModel()
   { 
       this.Price = 0;
   }

   [Display(Name = "Retail")]
   public double Price { get; set; }    
}
```

Comment: The property is `double`. Its already initialized to zero. The constructor is pointless!